# laravel - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hi am new to laravel framework and when i use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" type="text/css" />
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in master.blade.php am geting the following errors:

```
[2014-09-25 06:41:20] local.ERROR: exception  
'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:148
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1049):    
Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection-&gt;match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))</div>
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1017): 
Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))</div>
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(996): 
Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))</div>
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\
Application.php(777): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))       
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\
Application.php(747): Illuminate\Foundation\Application&gt;dispatch(Object(
Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\
Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;handle(Object(
Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)</div>
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php(47):    
Illuminate\Session\Middleware-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)</div>
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php(51): 
Illuminate\Cookie\Queue-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)</div>
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): 
Illuminate\Cookie\Guard-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)</div>
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\
Application.php(643): Stack\StackedHttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))    
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application-&gt;run()     
#11 {main} [] []
```

When i remove above two css & js references from the master.blade.php the error vanishes but keeping my own css and js referance does not give error. So anybody having an idea about this will be highly appreciated.
 
Thanks

Comment: Insert this in your template just to see the URL generated: `{{ dd(URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')) }}`. `dd` meaning die and dump.

Comment: Sir, dd removes all the links. sorry it could not helped me...

Comment: It stops the execution of the script and dumps the value, it's just to see the actual generated URL for debugging purposes.

Comment: @TshenchoTshering Are you really sure that the error is connected to your Blade template? For me it seems as it were error in routing (`routes.php` file)

Comment: A better way to include stylesheets and scripts is {{ HTML::style('link/to/style.css')}} and {{ HTML::script('link/to/script.js')}} @hebron dd means dump and die

Comment: @KhanShahrukh I guess it makes more sense that it dumps before dying... :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Guys...

problem is solved now. 
I used Clockwork for debugging in Chrome Developer tools and i found missing other reference needed by the css and script file.
[@Marcin Nabiałek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590451/khan-shahrukh)Thanks for showing better way to includ css and script file. :-)

Thanks all for ideas...